# Excel VBA Table Filter issues- Delete items in a table

Tags: excel, vba

When applying this code I am running into the issue that the top most filtered Item isn't being counted.
IE: When trying to delete the data within a Table if i have 1 entry TestEmptyTable() Returns False.
If i try to count the header as an entry and mark as >= 2 then it doesn't delete the top most entry. When it is >=1 It attempts to delete the whole sheet- When it is >1 it does nothing for the topmost entry but gets everything else. Referring to this section below when saying '>'
The Entire code is below the first code entry.
Any advise on how to get this Pesky first entry in my filtered tables?
Edit- I have learned the values that are being counted in tbl.Range.SpecialCells are not aligned with what i actually have, trying to fix that.

```
If tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.Count >= 2 Then
tblIsVisible = True
Else
If tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.Count < 1 Then
tblIsVisible = False
End If
End If
```

```html
'In Module6
Function TestEmptyTable()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim tblIsVisible As Boolean

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)

If tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.Count >= 2 Then
    tblIsVisible = True
    Else
    If tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.Count < 1 Then
    tblIsVisible = False
    End If
    End If
TestEmptyTable = tblIsVisible
    'MsgBox (TestEmptyTable)
End Function

Function DelTable()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If TestEmptyTable() = True Then
        'MsgBox ("TestEmptyTable = True")
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Delete
        Else
        'MsgBox ("TestEmptyTable= False")
        End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Function


'In Module5
Sub DeleteTable()
'
' 
'

'
    If Module6.TestEmptyTable = True Then
        Call Module6.DelTable
    End If
    
End Sub


'in Module1
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="MyFilterString"
    MsgBox (Module6.TestEmptyTable)'Still here from trying to test what happens.
    Call DeleteTable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some problems to understanding what you needed.
I think this code might help you achieved what you need.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim ol As ListObject: Set ol = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    
    If isTableEmpty(ol) Then
        Debug.Print "table empty"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Debug.Print "table not empty"
        If TableHasFilters(ol) Then
            Call TableDeleteFilteredRows(ol)
        Else
            ol.DataBodyRange.Delete
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function isTableEmpty(ol As ListObject) As Boolean
    If ol.ListRows.Count = 0 Then isTableEmpty = True
End Function

Function TableHasFilters(ol As ListObject) As Boolean
    TableHasFilters = ol.AutoFilter.FilterMode
End Function

Sub TableFilterRestore(ol As ListObject)
    If ol.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then ol.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End Sub

Function TableVisibleRowsCount(ol As ListObject) As Integer
    If ol.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
        TableVisibleRowsCount = ol.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
    End If
End Function

Sub TableDeleteFilteredRows(ol As ListObject)
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim olRng As Range
    Dim olRowHd As Integer
    Dim lrIdx As Integer
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer: i = 0
    
    ' Exit if table has no rows
    If ol.ListRows.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Set variables
    Set olRng = ol.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    olRowHd = ol.HeaderRowRange.Row
    
    ' Count filtered rows
    Dim nRows As Integer: nRows = TableVisibleRowsCount(ol)
    
    ' Redim array
    ReDim arr(1 To nRows)
    
    ' Popuplate array with listrow index of visible rows
    For Each rCell In olRng
        ' get listrow index
        lrIdx = ol.ListRows(rCell.Row - olRowHd).Index
        
        ' Add item to array
        i = i + 1
        arr(i) = lrIdx
    Next rCell
    
    ' Clear table filters
    Call TableFilterRestore(ol)
    
    ' Delete rows
    For i = UBound(arr) To LBound(arr) Step -1
        ol.ListRows(arr(i)).Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You got close enough that your answer helped to solve my issue.
Thank you.